# Filtered Lookup multiple Fields

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, filtered-lookup

I want to filter the lookup on multiple fields on one form. 
The problem is that only the last eventhandler I added applies to all fields. 
For this I wanted to use the context to get the field, which it is currently used.
But the filters are applied in the "onload" event of the form, where I don't have the selected context/field in it.

For this I use this code:

```
function preFilterLookupFunction(executionContext) 
{
   var fieldname = new Array("field1","field2");
   fLen = fieldname.length;

   for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) 
   {
      var tempName = fieldname[i];
      Xrm.Page.getControl(tempName).addPreSearch(function () 
      {
         addLookupFilterFunction(executionContext);
      });
   }
}

function addLookupFilterFunction(executionContext) 
{
   var attribute = executionContext.getEventSource();
   var tempFieldName = attribute.getName();
   alert(tempFieldName)
   var condition = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldContition").getValue();
   if (condition != null) 
   {
      var fetchXml = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='fieldContition' operator='eq' value='" + condition + "' /></filter>";            
      Xrm.Page.getControl(tempFieldName).addCustomFilter(fetchXml); 
   }    
}
```

My question: is it possible to get the context in the `addLookupFilterFunction` while executing, so I can set the filter to the right field? Or is there a better way to filter multiple field on one form?

Comment: Nice pic Twiebie.

Comment: You need to apply the same filter to more than one lookup on the form ? Did I get that right ? (Btw: this is the same code I'd have written at first)

Comment: @Alex yes, indeed . but I don't want to add the event handler for every field seperatly.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you do not need to pass an executionContext parameter.

In function call `addLookupFilterFunction(executionContext)` executionContext references the argument variable of function `preFilterLookupFunction(executionContext)`, which will be the same for every iteration of the `for` loop.

Replace this code:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(tempName).addPreSearch(function () 
{
   addLookupFilterFunction(executionContext);
});
```

by this:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(tempName).addPreSearch(addLookupFilterFunction);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it results in the same as before, only the last control in the list got the (right) filter, all other controlles get the filter of the last controll mentioned in the for loop. I have bypassed the problem by adding a seperate funtion for each controll and call it on load of the form, but the function with the loop for all controlls still not work.

Comment: When is `preFilterLookupFunction` called, once in the onload of the form?

Comment: yes, it is called one time in the onLoad of the form